# jquery div positioning

Tags: jquery, html, positioning

Can someone help with this jsfiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/4Ns44/

Intended purpose: when the page is scrolled down, link expands in the view port, This works good. But as we scroll up, I would like the expand window to stop where it started. ie, below the header div. Right now, the position:fixed is causing it to remain at top even after the header div becomes visible.

some help with `position:fixed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I think you want to check for when scrollTop is less than the original position of `#expand`. In particular:

```
var minY = $('#header').height();
```

In the `scroll` handler:

```
// this will reset to the original position
if (top < minY) {
    $expand.css({position: "absolute", top: ''});
}
```

Resulting in this: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ns44/3/

```
var minY = $('#header').height();
var $expand = $("#expand");

$(window).scroll(function () {

    var top = $(window).scrollTop();

    if($expand.css("position") === "fixed") {

        if(top > expandY) {
            $expand.css({position: "absolute", top: expandY});
        } else if (top < minY) {
            $expand.css({position: "absolute", top: ''});
        }
    }
    else {
        if (top < minY) {
            $expand.css({position: "absolute", top: ''});
        } else if(top < expandY) {
            $expand.css({position: "fixed", top: 0});
        }
    }
});
```

This is if I understand what you're trying to do...

Comment: I came across some minor issues. THe expand div is dynamic, and if the page is scrolled allway down and expand is called, if content height is longer than the current window, it gets clipped. Do you know how to increase the height of the window/ parent div in such case?

Comment: @tiffin here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/4Ns44/4/ 
expand is 1200px. but clickin on last <a> on left, expand gets clipped.

Comment: You could do something like [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ns44/5/). It solves the issue (I think) but the scrolling isn't quite as smooth because it's not using `position: fixed`.

Comment: Thanks, it is neat. The scroll flickr is ok, I can live with it. One thing i would like though is, once the expand is opened, and then window is scrolled up, expand moves up but if we scroll down, expand moves down until where it was opened. Is there anyway, once expand moves up when mouse scrollup, it does not come back to its original position (where it was opened) even if we scroll down after that? In other words, on scroll, expand should only move upwards.